# Error establishing context EIDA card reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, smartcard-reader, cardreader

Below is the code to read data from EIDA card using HID OMNIKEY 3121.

```
public void ReadData()
{
    ReaderManagement readerMgr = new ReaderManagement();

    readerMgr.EstablishContext();
    readerMgr.DiscoverReaders();

    PCSCReader[] readers = readerMgr.Readers;
}
```

The code works in the local system. Then I hosted the application in another server, say server A, and tried to access the web application from server B where the card reader is connected. But getting the error

> EmiratesId.AE.Exceptions.MiddlewareException: Error Establishing Context.
>      at EmiratesId.AE.ReadersMgt.ReaderManagement.EstablishContext()

in the line **readerMgr.EstablishContext()**.

Comment: have you installed SDK on server A?

Comment: @vikky YES. Installed.